Using iot-bench to write to cnsodb always reports an error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Using iot-bench to write to cnsodb always reports an error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Subsequently, I modified the write timeout of iotbench and cnosdb.
iotbench:
cnosdb/src/main/java/cn/edu/tsinghua/iot/benchmark/cnosdb/CnosDB.java
writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

cnosdb:
# query_tskv config
read_timeout_ms = "3000000ms"
write_timeout_ms = "3000000ms"

After I modified the above parameters and re-wrote the data, I found that there was still a write timeout error within the first three minutes.:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
cnosdb report the error as follow:
ERROR cnosdb::http::http_service: Failed to handle http write request, err: Coordinator { source: PreExecution { error: "status: Unknown, message: \"request timed out\", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {} }" } }

Has anyone encountered this problem?
